# how does yum use the baseurl in the repo file?

Tags: redhat, yum

I'm trying to mirror a rhel yum repo that has arrived on a box by satellite. reposync is failing (gpg check?) and I wanted to test things.

The repo config says the baseurl is something like:

```
https://blah/more-blah/rhel/7/server/$basearch/os
```

but that's really weird for these reasons:

- the server actually isn't https
- there is nothing on the end of that url
- there is something two levels up - but it's totally different

Does yum actually throw away the baseurl or decompose it somehow to be reconstructed in ways that reflect what it finds at some part of the endpoint?

Edit -- I can't show the actual config... it's a satellite derived one within an enterprise. But it's something like this:

```
[server-rpms]
sslclientcert = /etc/somefile
baseurl=https://blah/more-blah/rhel/7/server/$basearch/os
ui_repoid_vars = basearch
sslverify=1
name = Blah
sslclientkey = /etc/anotherfile
gpgkey = file:///etc/yet/another/file
enabled = 1
sslcacert = /etc/pemfile
gpgcheck = 1
```

By the way, yum works fine, this repo works.

Comment: Why do you believe that the server isn't https? For the rest, see [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-configuring_yum_and_yum_repositories).

Comment: Because it doesn't respond to a browser request. I'm told by someone that satellite makes repos that require client certs... so perhaps I'm not getting a browser response because of that. I'm not getting an error that would indicate that tho.

Comment: Your config does seem to specify a client certificate to use.